# My pattern in preg_match not working as i want

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to get:

- false for A3312+A192389+B2323+B948348
- false for A6712+A1922389
- false for A4512
- true for A4552+B948348
  (only one Aelement and one or more Belement)

I tried:

```
print_r(preg_match('/^A((?!\+A).)\+B(.*)$/', $string));
```

Comment: try `preg_match_all('/^A((?!\+A).)\+B(.*)$/', $string, $matches)`

Comment: `^A[\d]+\+B[\d]+$` should work for you, unless I've misread your requirement https://regex101.com/r/lF4oE8/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks as if the basic pattern you're after is *"A(digits)+B(digits)"*

Your expression seems a bit over-complicated for that purpose, I'd simply use:

```
preg_match('/^A\d+(\+B\d+)+$/', $input, $match);
```

If the input can be alphanumeric (A(alnum)+B(alnum), just use

```
preg_match('/^A[:alnum:]+(\+B[:alnum:]+)+$/', $input, $match);
```

instead.

Basically, the 2 absolute hard requirements are: the input string should start with an upper-case A, and there should be one + sign, followed by an upper-case B. Whatever the characters in between should be, you just have to add a character group that best fits your requirements. From the examples you gave `\d+` (one or more digits) seems to fit the bill. If *"A00FF33+B123ABC"* should be valid, I'd either use `[:alnum:]` or `[0-9A-F]` (for hex values) instead.

The trick for the one-or-more requirement is to create a group for the *+Belement* part of the match, and repeat that group one or more times:

```
\+B\d+ //matches once
(\+B\d+)+ //matches once or more
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will work for you:

```
^A\d+\+B\d+(?:\+B\d+)*$
```

Use it as:

```
preg_match('/^A\d+\+B\d+(?:\+B\d+)*$/', $string);
```

This matches `A` followed by digits the `+B` followed by digits repeated 1 or more times.

- `A4552+B948348` is matched,
- `A4552+B948348+B948348+B948348` is matched,
- `A3312+A192389+B2323+B948348` is not matched

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: One or **more** B element

Answer (score 1):

And with not-only decimals after A/B

```
^A[^\\+]+(?:\\+B[^\\+]+)+$
```